# Why is angularJS not binding data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

**I'm fetching maximum salary from `Employee` table. The JSON retrieves the data properly but why angular does not bind data?**

**`Controller.js`**

```
app.controller('AdminCntrl', function ($scope, AdminServices) {
    $scope.BtnSubmit = function () {
        alert('ok1')
        var Bust = AdminServices.Getmax();

        Bust.then(function (d) {
            $scope.Emp = d.data;

            })
        }
})
```

**`Service.js`**

```
app.service('AdminServices', function ($http) {

    this.Getmax = function () {
        var ss = $http({
            url: '/Department/Max',
            method: 'Get',
            data:JSON.stringify(),
            content:{'content-type' : 'application/Json'}
        })
        return ss;
    }
})
```

**`Controller`**

```
public JsonResult Max()
        {
               var xxx = db.Employees.OrderByDescending(ww => ww.Salary).First();
            return new JsonResult { Data = xxx, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
```

**`Emp.cshtml`**

```
<div ng-controller="AdminCntrl">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Min" ng-click="BtnSubmit()" />

        <div ng-repeat="Accessor in Emp">
            {{Accessor.Id}}
            <span style="color:red">{{Accessor.Name}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Fiddler Catch Data**

```
{"Id":11,"Name":"Saleem","Department":"Oracle","Salary":100000.00,"EmpType":"Admin","DataofJoin":"\/Date(1462127400000)\/","DataofBirth":"\/Date(597868200000)\/"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the value of `$scope.Emp`equal to your Fiddler Data?

It appears you're not returning an array which is what ng-repeat is expecting.  I'd bet if your Fiddler data was represented as an array:

```
[{"Id":11,"Name":"Saleem","Department":"Oracle","Salary":100000.00,"EmpType":"Admin","DataofJoin":"\/Date(1462127400000)\/","DataofBirth":"\/Date(597868200000)\/"}]
```

you'd see it bind.

Alternatively, if you're really not expecting an array then if you replace

```
<div ng-repeat="Accessor in Emp">
     {{Accessor.Id}}
     <span style="color:red">{{Accessor.Name}}</span>
</div>
```

with:

```
<div>
      {{Emp.Id}}
       <span style="color:red">{{Emp.Name}}</span>
</div>
```

You'd have some success

Comment: Thank u soo much Mr.Brad but can u tel me without ng-repaet how its wors

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question "can u tel me without ng-repaet how its wors".

Comment: i mean ng-repeat works as a foreach loop through it we will getting all the records 1 by 1 but here u did not use any repeat that my question ?Any how i got the ans

Comment: @MdHohn, you are using `.First()` in your Controller, so it isn't returning a list on the Data attribute.

Comment: @GregórioKusowski since the controller action is named **Max** I'd only expect one result returned, I assumed that was his intention too.